# Differences in rounded result when calling pow()

Tags: c++, c, pow

OK, I know that there was many question about pow function and casting it's result to int, but I couldn't find answer to this a bit specific question.

OK, this is the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    int j = 2;

    double d1 = pow(i,j);
    double d2 = pow(5,2);
    int i1 = (int)d1;
    int i2 = (int)d2;
    int i3 = (int)pow(i,j);
    int i4 = (int)pow(5,2);

    printf("%d %d %d %d",i1,i2,i3,i4);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output: "25 25 24 25". Notice that only in third case where arguments to pow are not literals we have that wrong result, probably caused by rounding errors. Same thing happends without explicit casting. Could somebody explain what happens in this four cases?

Im using CodeBlocks in Windows 7, and MinGW gcc compiler that came with it.

Comment: What do you want explained exactly? Both 24 and 25 are correct answers. The implementation just does whatever is most efficient.

Comment: My output is `25 25 25 25`. That's weird.

Comment: @user2448027 Try disable all optimization.

Comment: In Ubuntu system I also get "25 25 25 25", this happens only in Windows. And only in third case, and that's most interesting.

Comment: @Marko What happens if you disable all optimization in Ubuntu?

Comment: @user2448027 Sorry for my late answer. All optimizations are already disabled. But I also get correct result when using -O3 optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of the `pow` operation is 25.0000 plus or minus some bit of rounding error. If the rounding error is positive or zero, 25 will result from the conversion to an integer. If the rounding error is negative, 24 will result. Both answers are correct.

What is most likely happening internally is that in one case a higher-precision, 80-bit FPU value is being used directly and in the other case, the result is being written from the FPU to memory (as a 64-bit double) and then read back in (converting it to a slightly different 80-bit value). This can make a microscopic difference in the final result, which is all it takes to change a 25.0000000001 to a 24.999999997

Another possibility is that your compiler recognizes the constants passed to `pow` and does the calculation itself, substituting the result for the call to `pow`. Your compiler may use an internal arbitrary-precision math library or it may just use one that's different.

Comment: Rounding never changes a value above 25 to a value below 25. Even if one does not know the rules or mechanisms of floating-point arithmetic, the term “round” is a big clue: 24.999999997 is not rounder than 25.0000000001. Floating-point arithmetic is not a random-number generator.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree. That's not what I'm saying. What I'm saying is that rounding can turn a value that would have been 25 if not for rounding into 24.9999997 or 25.000001. and floating point arithmetic can be a random number generator in the sense that repeating the exact same operations is not guaranteed to produce the exact same results.

Comment: Repeating the exact same operations produces the exact same results. This is a case where the operations were **not** repeated because the C implementation fails to bind source code to floating-point operations unambiguously. Even so, each operation produces the same results each time it is executed. It is only that similar looking source code (not exactly the same) produces different results. This is a defect of the C implementation, not of floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You're arguing semantics and adding confusion and unnecessary complexity to a very simple question. Strictly speaking, you can never do the "exact same operation" twice. The problem is that you have no way to know what changes can lead to different floating point results. (If you change compiler versions, are you doing the exact same operations? If you upgrade the CPU, are you?) There is no "defect" here. This is how things are supposed to be. If there is a defect, it's in expectations.

Comment: It is not semantics because it tells you where to look for answers. If you look to the C standard for control over floating-point, you will have trouble. If you look to the IEEE 754 standard, you will find fully specified operations. In regard to your questions: If you change compiler versions, the operations are not necessarily the same. If you change the CPU model, the elementary operations are the same (esoteric operations like reciprocal-square-root-estimate may differ). You are advocating ignorance, asserting that these things cannot be known. But they can be known and controlled.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: This is a C question. It's not about IEEE 754. If you believe my statements are incorrect or misleading, we'll have to agree to disagree. If you think they're incomplete -- well, of course they are. From the standpoint of a C or C++ programmer trying to understand why floating point operations give them inconsistent results even when the operations appear to be identical from a language standpoint, the answer is quite simple -- the specification permits the implementation to provide any "reasonable" answer and does not require it to be consistent except that it be reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a combination of two problems:

- The implementation of `pow` you are using is not high quality. Floating-point arithmetic is necessarily approximate in many cases, but good implementations take care to ensure that simple cases such as `pow(5, 2)` return exact results. The `pow` you are using is returning a result that is less than 25 by an amount greater than 0 but less than or equal to 2<sup>–49</sup>. For example, it might be returning 25–2<sup>-50</sup>.
- The C implementation you are using sometimes uses a 64-bit floating-point format and sometimes uses an 80-bit floating-point format. As long as the number is kept in the 80-bit format, it retains the complete value that `pow` returned. If you convert this value to an integer, it produces 24, because the value is less than 25 and conversion to integer truncates; it does not round. When the number is converted to the 64-bit format, it is rounded. Converting between floating-point formats rounds, so the result is rounded to the nearest representable value, 25. After that, conversion to integer produces 25.

The compiler may switch formats whenever it is “convenient” in some sense. For example, there are a limited number of registers with the 80-bit format. When they are full, the compiler may convert some values to the 64-bit format and store them in memory. The compiler may also rearrange expressions or perform parts of them at compile-time instead of run-time, and these can affect the arithmetic performed and the format used.

It is troublesome when a C implementation mixes floating-point formats, because users generally cannot predict or control when the conversions between formats occur. This leads to results that are not easily reproducible and interferes with deriving or controlling numerical properties of software. C implementations can be designed to use a single format throughout and avoid some of these problems, but your C implementation is apparently not so designed.

Comment: I agree with everything but your last paragraph. It's actually worse when the implementation doesn't mix floating-point formats. Then your code will appear to work and bugs will slip by unnoticed. It is thanks to his implementation doing this that he has learned that he *cannot* rely on implementations to be predictable in an arena in which they in fact cannot be relied upon to be predictable. When you do something really wrong, the sooner and harder the implementation fails because of it, the better.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: That is a detrimental position which advocates that programmers accept compilers that are sloppy. When the behavior of a compiler makes it difficult to design good software, it should be considered a bug in the compiler. (Conformance to the C standard is **not** an endpoint for a compiler. They can and should go beyond it, and the standard should be improved in its floating-point specifications.)

Comment: Tightening the standard will result in worse performance for people who don't need the tightening. It may or may not be a good tradeoff, but I'm not convinced. So long as the standard permits the behavior, code will either have to be restricted to only running on compilers that are specified to behave in a particular way beyond the requirements of the standard or the code will be broken. I think it's wrong to argue that code should be built around the guarantees some specific compiler might provide, especially since you phrased your comment in terms of exhibited behavior, not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers here: just generally be **very** careful when working with floating point values.

I highly recommend reading this paper (even though it is a long read):
http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/28/14/29/PDF/floating-point-article.pdf

Skip to section 3 for practical examples, but don't neglect the previous chapters!

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure this can be explained by "intermediate rounding" and the fact that `pow` is not simply looping around `j` times multiplying by `i`, but calculating using `exp(log(i)*j)` as a floating point calculation. Intermediate rounding may well convert 24.999999999996 into 25.000000000 - even arbitrary storing and reloading of the value may cause differences in this sort of behaviuor, so depending on how the code is generated, it may make a difference to the exact result.

And of course, in some cases, the compiler may even "know" what `pow` actually achieves, and replace the calculation with a constant result.