# Optimal code binary case

Tags: c++

I am trying to get this output from my code:

```
0
10
110
1110
11110
111110
```

but what i get is

```
0
10
109
1110
11109
```

This is my code so far:

```
void optimal(int arrsize) {
  int j;
  int code = 0;
  cout << '0' << endl;
  for (int i = 1; i < arrsize; i++) {
    j = i;
    while (j > 0) {
      code += pow(10, j);
      j--;
    }
    cout << code << endl;
    code = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Rinzler sorry iam new here

Comment: No problem dude, just try next time to present a more readable question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is wasting resources through very expensive pow() call. You could achieve same results in optimal way with:

```
void optimal(int arrsize)
{
    cout<<'0'<<endl;
    for (int i = 1; i < arrsize ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < i ; j++)
        {
            cout<<'1';
        }
        cout<<'0'<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are very right also we can move the first line( cout<<'0'<<endl;)

Comment: Of course. This is just to demonstrate idea and can be modified to suit your needs. Also, it works with very big arrsize.

Comment: But any exact reasons why the algorithm in the question fails?? Despite both inputs in the `pow` function being integers??

Comment: As said by other person here, pow() takes double as input type so we get rounding error and at some point overflow.

Comment: yea.. but in the code in the question, it fails for `i=2`, 10^2 is 100.00000 (some more decimals maybe) But I dont get it how can it get rounded off to 99 (which then later sums uptp 109)

Comment: Implementation of pow() is not made in a way you expect it to be. As it doesn't work as 10^2 literally. In attempt to explain I'll try to make it simple: it is interpolating to resulting value. Technique is not quite trivial to explain.

Comment: @user007: It adds up to 99.999999999999 which is then rounded down. The round-to-nearest solution `int(pow(10,j)+0.5)` works by rounding 100.499999999 down to 100, as you probably expected.

Answer (score 2):

`pow` is a function for floating point, and you have then rounding error...

you may rewrite your function to something like:

```
void optimal(int arrsize)
{
    cout << '0' <<endl;
    int code = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrsize ; i++)
    {
        ++code;
        code *= 10;
        cout<< code << endl;
    }
}
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/BD7rk9)

Comment: so what function should i use

Comment: @AhmedELSaid: you may create your own function, or change your algorithm.

Comment: @AhmedELSaid Do you have a complete random number after `pow(11)`?

Comment: You will have overflow once result is bigger than `2147483647` (when `int` has 32bit).

Comment: @AhmedELSaid If you to go further, you should use the @Predrag's solution. Another thing, don't use `endl` but just `'\n'`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n

Comment: @Rinzler yes the number may reach pow(512222) thanx for the advice

Comment: Any more info about the round off error with the floats?? Still cant understand how can 10.000, 2.000 can round off to 99 (later sums to 109, for i=2)

Comment: @user007: You may read [differences-in-rounded-result-when-calling-pow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063102/differences-in-rounded-result-when-calling-pow)

Comment: If you want to be funny, using `std::oct` (octal) overflows one digit later :)