# C++ Program Giving Different Results on Different Computers

Tags: c++

My code is printing 192 for the input 100 (which is the desired result). But when I submit it on the online judge, it shows that the output of my program for the input 100 is 190. I copied and pasted the code in ideone.com and for input 100 I got result 192. I send it to my friend and on his PC the output is 190. But he also submitted the code onto ideone.com and got 192. What's the problem? Here's my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef long long int lli;

int main(){
   lli in,ans = 0;
   cin >> in;

   if(in < 10)
       cout << in << endl;
   else{
      lli digits = 0;
      lli temp = in;
      while(temp > 0){
         digits++;
         temp /= 10;
      }
     digits--;

     while(in > 0){
         //cout << "in: " << in << endl;
         //cout << "digits: " << digits << endl;

         ans += ((in - (pow(10,digits) - 1)) * (digits + 1));
         in = in -  (in - (pow(10,digits) - 1));
         digits--;

         if(in == 9){
            ans+= 9;
            break;
         }
      } 
      cout << ans << endl;
   }
}
```

ideone link: http://ideone.com/zOvHzW

Why is this happening? I understand that it may be a compiler issue but what is really going on in here?

Comment: Read CodeChef guidelines on how to process input and output! :)

Comment: Side note, [don't `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: why not include <bits/stdc++.h> ?

Comment: @RedwanulSourav Click on the link in Cory's comment.

Comment: I got rid of bits/stdc++.h. But no improvement in ouputs.

Comment: I found that on first iteration (when `in` is `100`) some compilers evaluate `in = in -  (in - (pow(10,digits) - 1));` as `98` and some as `99`(which is correct). I´m not sure why, I think that it will have to be something with optimization, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I wrote a custom power function, and the solution is accepted! What was wrong in pow() function? What is going on when I call the pow()? I solved the problem, but I still don't know what's wrong here.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063102/differences-in-rounded-result-when-calling-pow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `std::pow` is not exact. It is an approximating algorithm. The floating point result that it returns may be off by some, very tiny amount.

When you convert the floating point number to an integer, you round it down by removing the fractional part. But, if the correct result would have been say `100`, and the error was `-0.000...001` and therefore the result was `99.999...999` and you cut off the fractional part, then the integer that you get is 99.

How `std::pow` is implemented is... specific to the implementer. Therefore the error may be one way in one compiler / computer, but the other way in another. That is why the result may differ.

Solution: Don't use `std::pow` for integer calculation.

Workaround: Round the result to nearest integer first.

Comment: @RedwanulSourav no need to thank, that is what the upvote button is for. And don't forget to mark the most helpful answer as accepted :)