# Implementing RSA Encryption - pow() with large outputs

Tags: c, encryption, rsa, pow

I have given a homework about RSA Encryption, and I have wanted to complete this homework with C Programming Language. By the way, I am trying to find an answer for a problem connected with my code, not only about pow(), so it should not be marked as duplicate question.

```
int  *Encrypt(int* translation, int size){

int chunk;
const int E_RSA = 13;
double N_RSA = 2537;

// some codes...

//formulae = c = m^e mod n
encryptedMessage = fmod(pow(chunk,E_RSA) ,  N_RSA);

//some codes...

}
```

So here, when I calculate `pow(chunk,E_RSA)`, because my **E** value is 13, and let's assume that the message is **1900**, there will be an operation such as **1900^13**, and it will give a huge output. When I calculate it from a calculator, it give a different result from my C code. This difference is being a problem for the encryption. How can I solve it so that the **pow()** function will return result as precise as a scientific calculator ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: `pow` and `fmod` are for `double`, do not use floating point functions when you calculate with integers. You probably need a bigint library, or you take a look at modular exponentiation.

Comment: You don't actually need to calculate that big power... You should investigate modular exponentiation.

Comment: Hint:  calculating m^e is different from calculating m^e mod n.    Assuming `n` fits in a `int`, you won't need a bigint library.

Comment: Performing a modular exponentiation using the "dumb" way is not the best idea. There are algorithms for that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063102/differences-in-rounded-result-when-calling-pow) is not a good original. That is about errors in poor implementations of `pow`. This question is about finding a modulo residue in integer arithmetic. `pow` and floating-point arithmetic cannot be used to solve the problem in this question.

Comment: okay, still a duplicate. Better now?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre, the title of the question which you are saying  I am duplicating from is actually the answer my question. Calculating pow(a,b) mod n is not what I was looking for, simply I didn't know there is a different calculation for modular exponentiation.

Comment: okay, my job is done now :)